# ImportError: cannot import name 'inference' from 'paddle'

Tags: python, ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

I am trying to implement paddleocr. I have installed it using:

```
#Github repo installation for paddle
! python3 -m pip install paddlepaddle -i https://mirror.baidu.com/pypi/simple

#install paddle ocr
!pip install paddleocr

!git clone https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR.git
```

But while importing

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR,draw_ocr
```

I'm getting this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'inference' from 'paddle'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same error. My solution was to:

```
pip install paddlepaddle
```

Then I got another error (luckily you will not get this one but just in case) telling me to downgrade protoc to a version between 3.19 and 3.20, which I fixed by executing the following command:

```
pip install protobuf==3.19.0
```

After this I was able to execute the script that imported from paddleocr

Comment: For me, installing `paddlepaddle` was enough. I didnt get the downgrade protobuf error.

Comment: ```jovyan@jupyter:~$ pip install paddlepaddle
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paddlepaddle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for paddlepaddle```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's embarrassing, but if it helps anyone else avoid some frustration, it's worth it:

Make sure your file is not called `paddle.py`!

Comment: Yeah, made the same mistake! Thanks